# Reproducir dos <audio> a la vez

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un repositorio de audios en mi web y me gustaría poder reproducir más de uno a la vez, pero no consigo averiguar cómo hacerlo.

Os dejo el código por si alguno sabe la respuesta:

```js
var $player = $('.js-audio-player'),
  $playbackClass = 'is-playing',
  $fadeDuration = 500

$player.each(function(index) {
  var $this = $(this),
    id = 'audio-player-' + index

  $this.attr('id', id)

  $this.find('.js-control')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    resetPlayback(id)
    playback($this, $this.find('audio'), $this.find('video'))
  })

  // Reset state once audio has finished playing
  $this.find('audio')[0].addEventListener('ended', function() {
    resetPlayback()
  })
})

function playback($player, $audio, $video) {
  if ($audio[0].paused) {
    $audio[0].play()
    $video[0].play()
    $audio.animate({
      volume: 1
    }, $fadeDuration)
    $player.addClass($playbackClass)
  } else {
    $audio.animate({
      volume: 0
    }, $fadeDuration, function() {
      $audio[0].pause()
      $video[0].pause()
    })
    $player.removeClass($playbackClass)
  }
}

function resetPlayback(id) {
  $player.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this)

    if ($this.attr('id') !== id) {
      $this.find('audio').animate({
        volume: 0
      }, $fadeDuration, function() {
        $(this)[0].pause()
        $this.find('video')[0].pause()
      })
      $this.removeClass($playbackClass)
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li>
  <div class="audio-player js-audio-player">
    <button class="audio-player__control js-control">
        <div class="audio-player__control-icon"></div>
      </button>
    <h4 class="audio-player__title">Rain</h4>
    <audio preload="auto">
        <source src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3"/>
      </audio><img class="audio-player__cover" src="img/rain.jpg" />
    <video preload="auto" loop="loop">
        <source src="" type=""/>
      </video>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="audio-player js-audio-player">
    <button class="audio-player__control js-control">
      <div class="audio-player__control-icon"></div>
    </button>
    <h3 class="audio-player__title">Campfire</h3>
    <audio preload="auto" loop>
      <source src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_02.mp3"/>
    </audio><img class="audio-player__cover" src="img/campfire.jpg" />
    <video preload="auto" loop="loop">
        <source src="" type=""/>
      </video>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes reproducir los sonidos que quieras a la vez simplemente llamando al método `play` de cada uno. Te dejo aquí un ejemplo:

Al darle al play obtiene todos los elementos con clase `audio` y los reproduce. Al darle a stop para la pista 2 (para que se vea mejor que son dos sonidos reproduciéndose a la vez):

```js
var playBtn = document.getElementById('play');
var stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop');

var playSound = function() {
 $('.audio').each(function(index){
      $(this)[0].play();
    });
};

playBtn.addEventListener('click', playSound, false);
stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){audio2.pause()}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div>
   <audio id="audio1" class="audio" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto"  ></audio>
 <audio id="audio2" class="audio" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_02.mp3" preload="auto"  ></audio>
 <button id="play">Play</button>
 <button id="stop">Stop</button>
</div>

</body>
```